# i want to run a batch script into my pc when it is locked

Tags: windows, batch-file, remote-access

i want to run a batch file on my pc for an overnight activity. The problem is that i can't do that because the pc is locked.

I am using this code:

```
@echo off      
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq \\Desktop\notepad.exe" | find /i "\\Desktop\notepad.exe"      

IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO LOOP1
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO EXIT 

:LOOP1 
  start notepad.exe 
goto EXIT 

:EXIT
```

and it works only the pc is unlocked.

Any help will matters.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming problem. Super User is probably a better fit.

Comment: This might be solvable using a scheduled task, as well.

Comment: I tried scheduled task fro,m schedule task manager but when the pc is locked the task is not executing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new `Scheduled Task`. Set the task to run when user is `logged in or not`. Then set the interval of your task time.

On Windows 8 etc you are able to set triggers on when the task should be kicked of by using either a set time or when PC goes on idle, when an event occurs etc.
There is also an option for On `Workstation Lock`

If this is not your intention to use scheduler. Then right a script that runs in a permanent loop by adding some sleep time and only rerun the taks every now and again, something like this (untested, just used yours as example)

```
:START
@echo off      
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq \\Desktop\notepad.exe" |find /i "\\Desktop\notepad.exe"      

IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO LOOP1
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO EXIT 

:LOOP1 
  start notepad.exe 
  timeout 300
  goto START
```

`timeout 300` is basically sleeping the script for 300 seconds and will start from START again. We can then run the batch file before locking the PC and it wil lrun in a continuous loop. Even though it might not be the right way, it is an option. Perhaps some more detail around how often the batch file should run?

Comment: I used Task schedule with all possible combinations. When the pc is locked the schedule is not executing.

Comment: Windows version?

Comment: I used it on windows 7

Comment: did you set a password for the task? Also put in the full path to the notepad instead and create the task as the windows administrator and not local user.

Comment: After your comment i created a administrator account via "net user administrator /active:yes" command and then i set a password. I logged on Administrator account, i opened Task scheduler. I set my schedule task and it worked. My problem now is that the program that i want to open via the .cmd script located on a guest account. i tried the same but it didn't worked. Any suggestions? Also i disabled the  Accounts: Limit local account use of blank passwords to console logon only.

Comment: Admin should have access to any file. Can you explain why it is not working? Have any error messages?

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked. Now i have another problem. My server is running a dos application. Every night i want to reboot my server with a Task scheduler. But first is needed to quit the app in order to close gracefully, otherwise i will take some corrupted files. To quit the app i should press inside the window the character q. So i need a batch file to send q into the dos window.  I am using send keys function. When i run the batch it works but under a task scheduler ( the pc is locked) the task is not running. I read on google that there is not solution any suggestion?

Comment: If my solution helped you solve the issue, would you kindly mark the answer as correct? as for the new question, is the quit required in the same batch file or do you need to send it to the external dos program?

Comment: @ThodorisAlexopoulos Keep in mind that your application is running as a specific user. As which user does the application run and as which user is the scheduled task running?

Comment: From batch file i want to send a q into a dos application.  i.e  I am sending the q into a notepad and then i press enter.

Comment: WScript.CreateObject("WSCript.shell").AppActivate("test - Notepad")
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("q{ENTER}");

Comment: both runs under same user. the task Schedule runs with highest privileges.

Comment: Is the task set to run only when logged user is logged on? If it is, then it will not work, locked is the same as logged off.